# Fitting a product into the quintuple or Jacobi triple product

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, special-functions, q-series

The Rogers-Ramanujan functions fit nicely into the QPI or JTP. In fact we have that $$(q^{5};q^{5})_{\infty}(q,q^{4};q^{5})_{\infty}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}q^{\frac{(5n^{2}-3n)}{2}}$$ and we have $$(q^{5};q^{5})_{\infty}(q^{2},q^{3};q^{5})_{\infty}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}q^{\frac{(5n^{2}-n)}{2}}.$$
Is there a way to write $$ (q^{5};q^{5})_{\infty}(q,q^{4};q^{5})_{\infty}^{4}(q^{2},q^{3};q^{5})_{\infty}^{6} $$ as an infinite sum too?

Comment: The way you formulate the question, the answer is clearly yes. For instance, you could expand each factor using Euler's
$$(a;q)_\infty=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nq^{\binom n2}a^n}{(q;q)_n}$$
and write your product as a sum over $\mathbb N^{21}$. This is of course a trivial and uninteresting result. I don't know if there are any non-trivial and useful results about this particular product. It might help if you explain in what context you encountered it.

Comment: I encountered this product by trying to examine when it vanished mod 7. If i could write this as a single sum, the result will be so immediate. I knew of this expansions, by applying them would involve taking powers of the entire sum right? And that might make things more complicated.

Comment: Yes, it would be pointless to use the expansion I mentioned, it was just an example to show that your question "Is there a way to write $\dots$ as an infinite sum" is too general to be very meaningful.